# Repeated Function Application

Tags: python, recursion, lambda

I'm having trouble with a question which follows: Write a recursive function repeatedlyApply that takes as arguments a function
f of one argument and a positive integer n. The result of repeatedlyApply is a function of one argument that applies f to that argument n times.

So, for example, we would have

```
repeatedlyApply(lambda x: x+1,10)(100) ==> 110
```

You may assume that the following function has been defined. You don't have to use it, but it can contribute to a pretty solution.

```
def compose(f,g):
    return lambda x: f(g(x))
```

So far i've written this

```
def compose(f,g):
    return lambda x: f(g(x))

def recApply(f,n):
    for i in range(n):
        return recApply(compose(f,f), n-1)
    return f
```

I'm going wrong somewhere because using the above example  recApply(lambda x: x+1,10)(100) i get 1124.

Help much appreciated

Comment: You ended up adding `1024` instead of `10`. Think about why you got a power of `2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function needs some work:

- You have a `return` inside your `for` loop, so you return immediately instead of running the loop.
- You have a recursive call inside your `for` loop, so you are doing a bit too much iteration.  Choose one or the other.
- Be careful when you stack function compositions on top of each other, you are doing power composition rather than linear composition.

Can you tell us what precisely you are trying to do?

**EDIT:** Since everybody else is posting an answer:

```
recApply = lambda f, n: lambda x: x if n == 0 else recApply(f, n-1)(f(x))
```

Comment: It seems the code should be:recApply = lambda f, n: lambda x: x if n == 0 else recApply(f, n-1)(f(x)), otherwise the return value never changes

Answer (score 5):

Correct answer is:

```
def recApply(func, n):
    if n > 1:
        rec_func = recApply(func, n - 1)
        return lambda x: func(rec_func(x))
    return func
```

And the output:

```
>>>> print recApply(lambda x: x+1,10)(100)
110
```

Answer (score 3):

I have a solution based on lambdas:

```
>>> f = lambda x: x + 10
>>> iterate = lambda f, n, x : reduce(lambda x, y: f(x), range(n), x)
>>> iterate(f, 10, 3)
103
>>> iterate(f, 4, 4)
44
>>> f10 = lambda x: iterate(f, 10, x)
>>> f10(5)
105
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is an exercise of some sort. There are a few ways you could do it, here's a short one:

```
>>> repeatedlyApply = lambda f, n: reduce(lambda f1, f2: compose(f1, f2), [f]*n)
>>> repeatedlyApply(lambda x: x+1,10)(100)
110
```